# Dynamic Angular Output - is it possible?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have several parent components and I have created a common child component for all of them that must adapt dynamically and automatically to each case, among them several buttons that will be generated with a foreach using the data sent by the parent (name, CSS class and output name).

The question is: Can I create Output in a dynamic way that points directly to the function of the corresponding parent?

A quick solution I can think of is to use only one output that sends a string or integrates always to the same function of the parent and that this interprets it and derives it to the corresponding function with a switch but it seems to me a not very "elegant" and efficient solution.

For now I have tried to do this in the son component but the editor itself gives me an error:

componenteHijo.components.ts

```
@Input() misBotones: any[];
constructor() {
    this.misBotones.forEach(array => {
      @Output() array.nombreVariable: EventEmitter<number>;
    });
}
```

Of course I am sending from the father an array with all the necessary data:

componentePadre.components.html

```
<app-componente-hijo [misBotones]="botonesArray"></app-componente-hijo>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally with the help of the **"Stack Overflow en Español"** (Stack Overflow in Spanish) people I found the solution.

**1-** Dynamic Output cannot be used for a simple reason: the annotations/decorations 'Input' and 'Output' are used at compile time, not at run time.

They don't exist in Javascript and are used to add extra functionality at compile time, so you can't dynamically modify the code at run time.

**2-** As an alternative to this you can use eventHandler:

The parent component, within the data it prepares for the child component to display, can add a function that will be executed in response to an event on that element that is to be created.

In the example, a data array is created that has objects with two properties: eventHandler and text.

The child component receives that array and creates a series of buttons and in response to the click event, executes the function contained in eventHandler.

**Componente padre**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {

  data = [
    {
      eventHandler: () => {
        alert("boton 1");
      },
      text: "boton 1"
    },
    {
      eventHandler: () => {
        alert("boton 2");
      },
      text: "boton 2"
    }
  ];
  
}
```

**Componente hijo**

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "hello",
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let d of data">
      <button (click)="d.eventHandler()">{{ d.text }}</button>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
      h1 {
        font-family: Lato;
      }
    `
  ]
})
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() data: any[];
}
```

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cb5qt1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

[Link to the question in Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/414408/angular-output-din%C3%A1micos-es-posible)